# Databinding---Inserting empty row in a combo-box with DropDownList

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm new to Visual Studio and fixing a small bug in an application.

The combo box which exist is editable with DropDown eventhough it is has databinding. Because If I deleted a value, it would not save the change, I made it into a DropDownList; however, now I do not have the option of using null.

I have searched around and have been reading that I can insert an item before databinding. 
I have the bits and peices of the codes from different functions for this combo box. Not sure where to exactly make the change.

if someone could point me in the right direction, that'd be great.

```
private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox cmbSecCSR;
//----------------
this.cmbSecCSR = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
//---------------------
// cmbSecCSR
// 
this.cmbSecCSR.AccessibleRole = System.Windows.Forms.AccessibleRole.TitleBar;
this.cmbSecCSR.AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
this.cmbSecCSR.AutoCompleteSource = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
this.cmbSecCSR.DataSource = this.csrBindingSource2;
this.cmbSecCSR.DisplayMember = "Name";
this.cmbSecCSR.FormattingEnabled = true;
this.cmbSecCSR.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(112, 26);
this.cmbSecCSR.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
this.cmbSecCSR.MaxDropDownItems = 10;
this.cmbSecCSR.Name = "cmbSecCSR";
this.cmbSecCSR.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(184, 21);
this.cmbSecCSR.TabIndex = 2;
this.cmbSecCSR.ValueMember = "Username";
this.cmbSecCSR.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.comboBox_TextChanged);
this.cmbSecCSR.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.cmbBox_Entered);
// 
// csrBindingSource2
// 
this.csrBindingSource2.DataMember = "CSR";
this.csrBindingSource2.DataSource = this.productionDS;
//-------------------------
//loadUnboundData(); 
cmbSecCSR.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", productionMasterBindingSource, "CSR2", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

My Problem is similar to this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/fa277629-a65b-4799-9400-364f6f771739/

which is why I decided to change it to DropDownList;however, I don't know how to add the NULL Value in the DropDownList as it is bounded.

Comment: Are you trying to delete item from the list from GUI or something else..Can you make your question clear..

Comment: Instead of having an Editable drop down combo list I made the combo box into a DrownDownList. Hence users can only select. However, because they are populated with databind I do not have "NULL" option for Users to select from the combo box. My Question is where and how do i add that??

Comment: If you just want to add a blank line at the top of a DropDownList, you can do that after databinding.

Comment: Thanks I know that....But Since I am new to all this I'm not exactly sure where that would be. Above are some snippets of the code.

Comment: how did you bind your data to `csrBindingSource2`?

Comment: Well, not in the snippet you display. That looks like its from the VS-generated `InitializeComponent()`. Do not ever edit that code, manual changes will get dropped when recompiled. Instead, make your change in the constructor. You'll see `InitializeComponent()` called... after that.

Comment: I am still lost. Not sure

Comment: this.csrBindingSource2.DataMember = "CSR";
    this.csrBindingSource2.DataSource = this.productionDS;